Prove this equation has no positive integer solution?
Assume $a,b>0$ are distinct integers, prove that the following equation has no positive integer solutions $(m,n)$:
$$
\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{a^2+m}=\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{b^2+n}.
$$
It comes from an example in my topology textbook. The author simply says "one can easily verify".
My attempt is to assume $a>b$, then $a^2+m<b^2+n$ and $m<n$. Take another form
$$
\frac{a-b}{ab}=\frac{n-m-(a^2-b^2)}{(a^2+m)(b^2+n)}.
$$
But I cannot proceed anymore.

As you stated, assume WLOG that $a \gt b$. Since $a, b \gt 0$, then $a - 1 \gt 0$. We have
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{a^2 + m} - \frac{1}{a - 1} & = \frac{(a - 1) - a}{a(a - 1)} + \frac{1}{a^2 + m} \\
& = \frac{-(a^2 + m) + a(a - 1)}{a(a - 1)(a^2 + m)} \\
& = \frac{-m - a}{a(a - 1)(a^2 + m)} \\
& \lt 0
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$
Alternatively, and somewhat more directly, for any real $m \ge 0$, there's
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{a^2 + m} & \le \frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{a^2} \\
& = \frac{a + 1}{a^2} \\
& = \left(\frac{1}{a - 1}\right)\left(\frac{a^2 - 1}{a^2}\right) \\
& \lt \frac{1}{a - 1}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$
From either of the above results, and $a - 1 \ge b \;\to\; \frac{1}{a - 1} \le \frac{1}{b}$, we get
$$\frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{a^2 + m} \lt \frac{1}{a - 1} \le \frac{1}{b} \lt \frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{b^2 + n}$$
This shows, more generally, there are no non-negative real solutions $(m, n)$.

purely inequalities,  for some $x,t >0$   integer we have
$$  \frac{1}{x}  < \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{x^2 + t}  < \frac{x+1}{x^2}   $$
Increase $x$ by $1$   to get something similar,
Claim $$  \frac{1}{x+1}  < \frac{x+2}{(x+1)^2} <   \frac{1}{x}  < \frac{x+1}{x^2}   $$
Putting it in this order, all we need for the inner pair is crossed products
$$ (x+2)x  < (x+1)^2   $$
which is just true.
